# mysql : Insert Ignore with multiple unique index

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have a table with millions of records and its increasing day by day, so want to create **unique index** on that table.

Already removed null values to some default values.

so in InnoDB max length of unique index 3072 bytes, and in the **unique index** of multiple columns, each column takes **767 bytes**. I have to create a unique index on 10 columns. which is large huge from the max number of bytes.

so can we have multiple **unique index** on the table so **INSERT IGNORE** statement can be utilized?

Thanks,